# Error Installing Single Assignment C (SAC)

Tags: gcc

I followed the [instructions](http://www.sac-home.org/release/GETTING-STARTED) to download and install SAC, however, upon executing the "make fast" command I receive the following error:

```
maxx@ubuntu:~/sac2c-1.00-beta-linux-x86_64/stdlib$ make fast  
make -f buildfile MODE=lean
cd modules/structures/lib/..; sac2c -v0 -g -O3 -linksetsize 0   ScalarArith.sac -o lib

****ABORT: line 0  file: /usr/include/stdc-predef.h
ABORT: syntax error at pos 36: '3`
ABORT: # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
ABORT:**                                    ^**

*** Compilation failed ***
*** Exit code 1 (Loading SAC program)
*** 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s)

make[1]: *** [modules/structures/lib/libScalarArithTree.so] Error 1
make: *** [fast] Error 2
maxx@ubuntu:~/sac2c-1.00-beta-linux-x86_64/stdlib$
```

​
I am not sure how to proceed here, I am thinking it may be a problem specific to my environment, but it seems highly specific.

I did some looking around and found this article on gcc which had the following to say:

Pre-processor pre-includes

The GCC pre-processor may now pre-includes a file that defines certain macros for the entirety of the translation unit. This allows fully conformant implementations of C99/C11 and other standards that require compiler or compiler + runtime macros that describe implementation availability.

On linux,  is pre-included.

This subtle change means that some more creative uses of the pre-processor may now fail, with the following diagnostic:

```
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:0: error: Syntax error near '3' 
As a workaround, the stdc-predef.h preinclude can be disabled with the use of -ffreestanding. For non C/C++ code, use the pre-processor flag -P.
```

Then I tried recompiling with

```
make "CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding" fast
```

And still no luck. Any ideas? Below is my architecture information

```
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-35-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be possible to override the preprocessor definition used by the sac2c binary itself by creating a `$HOME/.sac2crc` file with appropriate definitions for `CPP_STDIN` and/or `CPP_FILE`. I was able to do that by modifying the `$SAC2CBASE/setup/sac2crc` file i.e. to inhibit line-marker generation by adding the `-P` flag

```
sed 's/gcc -E/& -P/' $SAC2CBASE/setup/sac2crc > ~/.sac2crc
```